# Is it possible to use standard tokens in a views field?

Tags: views, tokens

I am using Drupal 7.38 and [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) (7.x-3.11) to show fields. I can't seem to get standard token replacement working for text fields, e.g. `[node:created]` is not replaced with the relevant value.

This seems to work fine if I set views to show content rather than fields. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I found for this was the [Advanced Text Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_text_formatter) module, which allows you to set a new text format for text fields within Views, including an option to replace Tokens.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing - use a token in a Global custom text field in a view. I've installed the Advanced Text Formatter module, but can't see how to use it to configure the field. Thinking I'm missing something obvious, but perhaps not. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: **// I'm trying to do the same thing - use a token in a Global custom text field in a view. //** The functionality works with text and longtext fields on content types. Looking to add this to a Global custom text field in Views might be unsupported.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to display the date the node was posted or created when showing fields, you don't need to use a token. Simply add the field `Content: Post date` to the fields of the view.

If you want to include this date in a `Global: Custom text` field in your View, be sure to have the field `Content: Post date` **above** the `Global: Custom text` field. The replacement pattern for the post date will appear by clicking on `Replacement Patterns` inside the custom text field (usually named `[created]`). You can also select `Exclude from display` in the post date field if you don't want it to show.

**EDIT:**
Re-read your question, and I guess you are using [Token Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_filter) to insert tokens like `[node:created]` in a `Long text` field in your node, right? If this is the case, I'm afraid Views will not do a token replacement when rendering the field. There may be a way to modify the Views formatter to do this, but that's beyond my skills. See [this post](https://www.drupal.org/node/1417266) for a similar situation - you are able to use token replacements in your Views Header or Footer custom text, but not in a Field.

Comment: Thanks for the response, yes that's right the tokens are within a Long text field. I've just now managed to find a solution to this using the [Advanced Text Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_text_formatter) module which gives an extra option within Views to format text fields and a simple checkbox for token replacement.

Comment: Wonderful. Good to know. You should post an answer and mark it as correct yourself, for future people looking for this. They encourage this in this forum.